# Resize facebook permission dialog in firefox using gigya

Tags: facebook, dialog, resize, gigya

I am using gigya to connect to facebook and have included almost all the permissions for connecting. In firefox i could not see the Allow button as the permission dialog size is too big. Did anyone had this problem while connecting with gigya ?

Can scroll bars be added to permissions dialog ?

Comment: can you please provide the code you are using? and a screenshot of the result you are seeing will be nice

Comment: I have fixed this one. After lots of research i came to know that gigya doesn't allow to configure the permissions dialog. So i connected facebook through graph api. Its done now

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the window using a JS proxy function:

```js
if (!gigya) {
    return;
}

var providerCache = {};

// Proxify the _getProviderByName method on gigya, 
// then alter the dimensions values of the results.
var proxied = gigya.socialize._getProviderByName;
gigya.socialize._getProviderByName = function(name) {
    var provider = proxied.apply(this, arguments);
    if (!(name in providerCache)) {
        provider.width += 100;
        provider.height += 100;
        providerCache[name] = provider;
    }
    return provider;
}
```

This code will increase the dimensions of the popup window by 100px.